# She ended up (being??) a rich woman

Tags: adjectives, phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases, noun-phrases

1. Somehow they all **ended up** *at my house*. ("end up" + prepositional phrase)
2. Well, grades ended up to be unimportant after all as my first job after graduating **ended up** *in a private school* with a very low pay scale. ("end up" + prepositional phrase)
3. She **ended up** *a rich woman*. ("end up" + noun phrase)
4. Maybe I'll **end up** *a journalist*. ("end up" + noun phrase)
5. She'll **end up** *penniless* if she continues to spend like that. ("end up" + adjective)
6. That could **end up** *catastrophic*. ("end up" + adjective)

Are they all correct? Or do they all need "being" after "end up"? For example:

Maybe I'll **end up** ***being** a journalist*.

When should we use "end up" + **being** + noun phrase/adj phrase/adverb phrase/prep. phrase, and when should we use "end up" + noun phrase/adj phrase/adverb phrase/prep. phrase?

Comment: ***End up***: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/end-up - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/end%20up - *She ended up a rich woman.*

Comment: Do you mean the OP sentences are all correct as they are? Because the dictionaries that you mention nowhere use the word "being" with "end up".

Answer (score 2):

*End up* is an idiom meaning 'come finally to (some situation or conclusion)' and can take a gerund complement describing the end state, which can be a predicate adjective or noun (with a *being* auxiliary). It has pretty much the same meaning and grammar as *wind up*.

- *She ended up going to the movies after all.*
- *She ended up writing about her mother.*
- *She ended up being bored out of her skull.*
- *She ended up being too weak to stand.*
- *She ended up being the assistant producer.*

Auxiliary forms of *be* can be deleted by many rules, since they're predictable, so *Whiz*-deletion and *to be*-deletion are common in relative clauses and infinitive complements. This also happens to *being* auxiliaries with *end up*:

- *the man **who was** standing on the corner ==> the man standing on the corner*
  (*Whiz*-deletion)
- *He's considered **to be** lazy* ==> *He's considered lazy*
  (*to be*-deletion)
- *She ended up **being** a country lawyer ==> She ended up a country lawyer.*
  (*being*-deletion)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know where to start ...

In all cases, “up” is an adverb that carries the meaning of “finally or completely”.

Compare:

He opened the box - this does not say how far he opened the box - perhaps just a little...

He opened the box **up** / He opened **up** the box. He opened the box completely, e.g. he took off the lid.

To end up is probably a phrasal verb  = to complete a journey (in space or time.)

1 **end[ed] up** = verb + adverb, *at my house* is an adverbial prepositional phrase.

2. as above
3. **a rich woman** is a noun phrase acting as an adverb – she ended up **as** a rich woman.
4. as above. (Quite amusing if up were a preposition.)
5. **Penniless** is an adjectival free modifier

6 As above