# Omitting "to be", "that", "it is" all in the same sentence?

Tags: verbs, adverbs, be

I encountered the following in a 1958 book on investing:

> How has the market price of these shares responded to all this? Has the price-earning ratio continued to advance as, twenty-two months ago, **I indicated appeared probable?**

The last part made bold is the difficulty for me.

So I can ignore the middle sentence "twenty-two months ago", and focus on

> Has the price-earning ratio continued to advance as I indicated appeared probable?

In this question, it seems to me that some words are missing. I can guess the meaning is

> Has the price-earning ratio continued to advance as I indicated **(that) (it)** appeared **(to be)** probable?

But it looks like there are several grammatical rules involved here, that the author used to omit these parts, and I can't understand the interplay of these rules.

Could you help explain the rules which allowed the author to write this question in such form?

I know it involves omitting "to be" after linking verbs such as "appear," and that you can omit "that" before complements, but why "it" can be omitted, whether after "as" or in general? or otherwise is there some other grammatical rule that I'm missing here?

Comment: It's grammatical. Personally, I find the _indicated appeared probable_ string clumsy and would leave the _to be_ in place. Even then 'to appear probable' smacks of redundancy. Avoiding the past perfect (as I _had_ indicated) is normal where it is not absolutely unavoidable; here, inserting it changes the meaning/timeframe (and would perhaps be a necessary correction, but we can't be sure). Inserting a 'that' would be non-standard.

Comment: What @EdwinAshworth said. But it's not so much that the text could benefit from a few "function words, linking verbs, etc." as that the ***contrived sequence / inversion*** is awkward. ***Has the price-earning ratio I indicated appeared probable twenty-two months ago continued to advance**?* strikes me as far easier to parse (it *might* be a bit better with ***that*** after ***ratio***, but that's no biggie).

Comment: I attempted an answer but am giving up because I'm doing a bad job of it. Just to point out for others, though, Tamir never suggested the sentence was invalid, and didn't ask about rewrites. The question, as I see it, is: In the sentence "I indicated [that] it appeared probable [that] the ratio would etc.," why can we omit the "that"s? and in the construction "it appeared [to be] probable," why can we omit "to be"? These ought to be easy to answer, but I'm bungling it.

Comment: @Andy Bonner _to be-deletion_ has been covered here on ELU several times. See for example [John Lawler's answer here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/575498/she-ended-up-being-a-rich-woman/575503#575503).

Comment: And ["that"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses) (though it's a bit hard to get a quick answer from that page. [This BBC q-a post](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv336.shtml) might be more useful...)

Comment: [Ann Borkin's paper](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/tobeandnottobe.pdf) is a good start on _to be_-Deletion.

Comment: And [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57088/15299) deals with several different deletion rules.

Comment: "as I indicated was probable" is definitely better. The quoted text is hedging too much. (I realise this is not the question.)

Comment: "...as I indicated was probable", maybe "...as I indicated seemed probable", and some other copulas seem OK but maybe appeared is just too awkward.

Answer (score 1):

The *it* in your guess at the meaning of the original is a pronoun that must be used with an extraposed subject as its referent.

> [That the price-earnings ratio will continue to advance] appears
> probable.
>
> ***It*** appears probable [that the price-earning ratio will continue to
> advance].

Including the declarative content clause (*that*-clause) as subject would result in an ungrammatical construction.

> *Has the price-earning ratio continued to advance as I indicated ***that it would*** (***continue to advance***) appeared probable?

Including the *it* without the extraposed subject would lead to an ungrammatical construction as an implied one is not allowed.

> *Has the price-earning ratio continued to advance as I indicated ***it*** appeared probable?

With the extraposed subject included, the construction is once again grammatical, but the addition seems unnecessary.

> Has the price-earning ratio continued to advance as I indicated ***it*** appeared probable ***that it would*** (***continue to advance***)?

The best choice in respect to the omission of the embedded clause understood as subject of *appeared* is probably the one the author made.

An example of a similar omission would be in a *how*-relative clause.

> I could stand up to the Republican leaders and vote how I believed was
> right.
>
> I could stand up to the Republican leaders and vote how I believed
> ***it*** was right ***for me to vote***.

Comment: +1 for the correct analysis, although I would think the original is not terribly easy to parse. I would have written something like _Has the price-earning ratio continued to advance as I indicated it probably would?_

Answer (score 0):

## Simple answer

In the sentence,

> Has the price-earning ratio continued to advance as I indicated
> appeared probable?

the ***it***, as pronoun for *price-earning ratio*, can be omitted because the subject has already been mentioned. Sometimes we can omit words if they're repeating the same information. This is known as **[ellipsis](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/ellipsis)**.